# Comparison of reverse geocoding by Google and by Apple

Tags: ios, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api, clgeocoder

I need to compare reverse geocoding [by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and [by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html)

I'm developing an app for iOS and plan to port it to Android, and it's crucially important that the names given by Google and Apple geocoder would be the same.

I compared how they work in some locations and didn't see the difference. But the fact that I didn't find it doesn't mean that there isn't one.

So my question is: are the names given by Apple and Google reverse geocoder different?

Comment: There are differences! Working with Swedish cities, I´ve found a couple of differences (Google returns Luleå, Apple returns Lulea). Google got, in my opinion, better city data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably doesn't answer your question, but you could just use google's [geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) in both your iOS and android apps. iOS can get JSON data from google's apis and turn it into a NSDictionary which you can read, so there is no reason you have to use the iOS library.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget in google's terms of use, it says you can only display the data on google maps.